# Regex to test if string is enclosed in [brackets] using c#

Tags: c#, regex

Im having strings that may or may not be enclosed by brackets

```
string a = "[Hello world]";
string b = "Hello world";
```

The following regex returns true as long as the string contains [], but that's not the goal :)

```
var c = "hello[ ]world";
var isCommandArray = Regex.IsMatch(c, @"\[.*?\]"); // returns true
```

Thanks

Comment: regex is really not required here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `^` for start of pattern and `$` for end of pattern.

```
var isCommandArray = Regex.IsMatch(c, @"^\[.*?\]$")
```

Answer (score 7):

If you allow other brackets to be in the middle, you don't have to use `Regex`:

```
bool isBracketed = s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]");
```

If you **don't** allow other brackets in the middle, you could still do this:

```
bool isBracketed = s.LastIndexOf("[") == 0 && s.IndexOf("]") == s.Length - 1;
```

Comment: +1 That's called wisdom: don't use regex where you don't need to!

Comment: @CédricRup, I disagree. You should use regex as often as possible

Comment: @Rotem LOL of the day :). Building with Regex is powerful and agile, string juggling like above is nice sometimes but when things shall get more complex it sucks and you know it.

Comment: @Trikks My problem is with statements like "as often as possible". I think you should strive to use the right tool for the job - whatever is most readable, maintainable and performant. In this case I think it's string juggling. In a slightly more complex case it would definitely be Regex. I guess it all comes down to a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to code the regex so it matches the start and end of the string.

```
^\[.*?\]$
```

`^` indicates the start of the string, and `$` indicates the end.

If you wanted to allow whitespace around the braces you would add `\s`:

```
^\s*\[.*?\]\s*$
```

Comment: I think you don't need the lazy quantifier `?` if you're specifing the beginning and ending anchors.

Comment: @Mathew Probably, I just left it in from the OP's example.